# Is it guaranteed by the C++ standard that cin, cout, etc. will be created first and destroyed last?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

`cin`, `cout`, basic streams related - is it guaranteed anywhere in the standard that these obejcts will be created first and destroyed last?

It would implicate that non-local static objects can rely on them in their constructors and destructors (no ctor race between these objects and the basic streams).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are guaranteed to be created before any static object declared after including `<iostream>` and, in any case, before starting `main`. They are not destroyed during program execution.

Including the header has the effect of declaring a static variable of type `ios_base::Init`, whose creation ensures that the standard streams are initialised.

If you want the Standardese for this:

> C++11 27.4.1 [iostream.objects.overview]/2: The objects are constructed and the associations are established at some time prior to or during the first time an object of class `ios_base::Init` is constructed, and in any case before the body of main begins execution. The objects are not destroyed during program execution. The results of including `<iostream>` in a translation unit shall be as if `<iostream>` defined an instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration. Similarly, the entire program shall behave as if there were at least one instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration.

Comment: `main` is not the only thing, a programmer would write. Globals and statics are also candidate.

Comment: @Ajay: Indeed, which is why `main` is not the only thing I mentioned. As I said, the streams are guaranteed to be created before any static object declared after including `<iostream>`.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong Mike, but I doubt. Why: I may have multiple headers, included in proper sequence (or not). There is no guarantee that first headers will be put into linker/loader's initialization phase in that given sequence. Or there is guarantee? If no, inclusion of `<iostream>` is nothing but text-inclusion. Yes, I am aware actual code of stream class reside in runtime library (DLL, SO or static-lib). If that's the case, it is guaranteed that DLL/SO/LIB objects would be initialized first? Again, what's the guarantee of order there?

Comment: @Ajay: I've said exactly what the guarantee is. If you include the header (which is guaranteed to insert its contents at the inclusion point) then any static objects declared afterwards, in the same translation unit (so libraries etc. have nothing to do with this), will be initialised after the streams. If you declare a static object without first including the header, there is no guarantee.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: thank you for both the answer and standard reference, I'll accept this as your answer points to the standard directly, although the explanation in James' answer seems easier to follow with a real-life example

Comment: @hauron: James' answer is also clearer about what *isn't* guaranteed - including the header before the constructor definition isn't enough, it must also come before the static object's definition.

Comment: @hauron Mike's answer gives the literal rules.  I didn't repeat them in my answer, because they'd already been stated.  I answered because I thought it worth describing the _limits_ of these guarantees, but my answer isn't complete without Mike's.

Comment: I wonder if it's worth pointing as well that in practice, at least since the days of CFront, most implementations have taken steps to ensure that at least one instance of `ios_base::Init` was constructed before any initializers written by the user were run.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer to your question is no.  As others have pointed out,
there *are* guarantees for objects defined in translation units
including `<iostream>`, at least if the object is defined after the
inclusion.  But this doesn't always help: you include `<iostream>` in
the translation unit which defines the constructor, not necessarily in
the one which defines the static variable.  So cases like the following
are possible:

file1.hh

```
class X
{
public:
    X();
};
```

file1.cc

```
#include "file1.hh"
#include <iostream>

X::X()
{
    std::cout << "Coucou, me voila!" << std::endl;
}
```

file2.cc

```
#include "file1.hh"

X anX;
```

In this case, it's quite possible that the constructor of `anX` be
called before `std::cout` is constructed.

To be on the safe side: if the constructor of an object which might be
used as a static variable wants to use any of the standard streams, it
should probably declare a local static of type `ios_base::Init`:

```
X::X()
{
    static ios_base::Init dummyForInitialization;
    std::cout << "Coucou, me voila!" << std::endl;
}
```

If `std::cout` wasn't already constructed when this constructor is
called, it will be when the static variable is constructed.

Comment: Thank for the useful example "pretending" to be cout/cin safe :)

Comment: This answer from a practical standpoint is more useful - it shows an example and how to resolve the problem. The question asked about the standard, but I do believe the answers together form "the perfect answer", hence I've chosen Mike's answer, and voted for this.